# MacVim always return focus to terminal upon leaving

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I'm running Mavericks and I recently started playing around with `sshfs` to try to boost my productivity by using MacVim (I've been using in-terminal vim for a few years now).  I really like MacVim.

I only have one issue so far.  I've configured MacVim to hide after closing, which is perfect.  Suppose I want to edit `main.cpp`, I simply launch `mvim main.cpp` from the cmd line and MacVim opens up.  When I'm done with `main.cpp`, I close MacVim (via `:wq`) and my terminal regains focus right away.  Perfect.

The only issue I face is that if, while editing `main.cpp`, I focus to another window, say, Google Chrome to look something up, then continue editing `main.cpp`.  After closing `main.cpp`, Google Chrome would regain focus rather than my terminal.

**Is there any way to force MacVim to remember from where it was launched and always regain focus to that place?  I will always launch MacVim from a terminal.**

Comment: MacVim's Vim can be run in a terminal, which would allow you to use sshfs there. All you need to do is find `mvim` in your path, and then make a symlink to the same target there but call it `vim`. That will override the Apple-provided Vim, giving you all of MacVim's features in the terminal.

Comment: Agreed, although one of the things I like most about MacVim GUI is the fact that I do not lose a terminal window to Vim.  For example, up until I started using MacVim, I would have side-by-side terminal windows, one where vim would be open editing files, and another where I would run bash commands.  Using GUI vim, I do not have to sacrifice a terminal window, it just opens. I would prefer to keep that functionality.

Comment: Why do you want MacVim to quit on `:q`? Why don't you simply keep it running?

Comment: @romainl: If you leave it running in the background, then I'll have to cmd+tab into Terminal since it won't focus on it automatically.

Comment: I've +1'd your comment since it was a combination of your comment and @Fdinoff's answer that helped me fix it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the following to your gvimrc or wrap in a `has("gui_running")` check in your vimrc

```
autocmd VimLeave * :!open -a Terminal
```

to bring Terminal to the front when MacVim quits. This uses the open command to open a new Terminal Window or bring the current one to the foreground.

Change Terminal to iTerm2 if you use iTerm2

Comment: This didn't work for me. I added `if has("gui_running") 
  autocmd VimLeave * :!open -a Terminal
endif` to my `.gvimrc` and it still focuses on Chrome upon leaving.  Interestingly, the same effect is not observed if I switch to Word and back to MacVim, then it goes to Terminal.  It seems that only if I focus to Chrome and then back to MacVim, it'll go back to Chrome after.

Comment: I should also mention that this is especially annoying since I usually run my Chrome on a different "Desktop" than my Terminal & Macvim (in the OS X Mavericks sense, what was before Expose I believe).  This means that when I close MacVim (if I had lost focus to Chrome), my entire screen changes to Chrome whereas I had wanted it to stay on the same screen and switch back to Terminal. Thought I'd add a little more clarification.

Comment: @Amit You don't need the `has("gui_running")` if placing it in your gvimrc. I can replicate the behavior with Terminal. I can't with iTerm2. You might consider looking at an osascript solution if you want to stick to Terminal.

Comment: The right answer was actually a combination of your answer and the suggestion made by @romainl in the comments above.  If I set MacVim to continue running in the background after exiting using `:q`, then the `autocmd` will execute and will focus to Terminal.  Before, when it had MacVim hide after `:q`, it wasn't focusing because apparently the `autocmd` wasn't executing for some reason?  Thanks for everyone's input here!

Comment: The name of iTerm2 is actually iTerm.app, so in order to have it return to iTerm2, you have to do: autocmd VimLeave * :!open -a iTerm

Answer (score 4):

This might be obvious already, but if you change MacVim's preferences item "After last window closes:" to "Hide MacVim", then I think you'll get something close to the behavior you want: when you start mvim from the terminal, and then finish a file, focus will return to the Terminal as long as you don't have other MacVim windows open. At least, this gets me the behavior I prefer...

Comment: Not a very good solution since I always have multiple MacVim windows open.